# Redux-Saga: Async Task being called twice

Tags: redux-saga

I'm new to redux-saga and trying to replace redux-thunk in my React application. For some strange reason, my async task (worker) is being executed twice (but only when there's an AJAX request inside -- doesn't happen when there is a normal side effect e.g., console.log).

As you can see from below, I call my getChildData only once in componentDidMount. However, my getChildDataAsync generator function executes twice (unless I comment out getChildData (which is an async request returning a promise). The request works and I see my response data, but then another request is fired off.

At first I thought this may have to do with location change but this happens on first visit to the website/hard refresh.

Here is how I have saga set up:

**saga.js**

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { call, put, take, cancel, takeLatest } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import { push, LOCATION_CHANGE } from 'react-router-redux';
import {
  CHILD_DATA_LOADING,
  CHILD_DATA_SUCCESS,
  CHILD_DATA_ERROR,
} from 'src/redux/actions/actionTypes';
import { getChildData } from 'src/api/search';

// Worker Saga - API Request
export function* getChildDataAsync(action) {
  const { id } = action;
  const params = { id, storageKeys, dataCategory, from };

  try {
    const response = yield call(getChildData, params);
    yield put({
      type: CHILD_DATA_SUCCESS,
      childData: response.data,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    yield put({
      type: CHILD_DATA_ERROR,
      childDataError: true,
      error,
    });
  }
}

// Watcher Saga
export function* watchGetChildData() {
  const childWatcher = yield takeLatest(CHILD_DATA_SUCCESS, getChildDataAsync);
}

// Root Saga - Generator Function
export default function* rootSaga() {
  yield [
    // Combine all watcher sagas
    watchGetChildData(),
  ];
}
```

**store.js**

```
// @flow
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { routerMiddleware } from 'react-router-redux';
import createHistory from 'history/createHashHistory';
import rootReducer from 'src/redux/reducers/index';
import { createLogger } from 'redux-logger';
import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga';
import rootSaga from 'src/redux/sagas/sagas';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

// React Router Redux
export const history = createHistory();

// Redux Saga
const sagasMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();

// Add Redux Logging Only to DEV/TST Environments
const middleware = applyMiddleware(thunk, sagasMiddleware, routerMiddleware(history));

// Create store
const store = createStore(rootReducer, middleware);

// Run Redux-Saga Watchers
sagasMiddleware.run(rootSaga);

export default store;
```

**childDataCreator.js**

```
// @flow
import {
  CHILD_DATA_SUCCESS,
  CHILD_DATA_ERROR,
} from 'src/redux/actions/actionTypes';


// Description: Async Request to Get Child Data for Vendors/Sets
export function getChildData(
  id: string,
) {
  return { type: CHILD_DATA_SUCCESS, id };
}
```

**React Component**

```
class DataView extends Component<Props> {
  componentDidMount() {
      const _id = '12345';
      this.props.getChildData(_id);
    }
  }

  rest of class....
```

Comment: Would be helpful and faster if you have Plunker example or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the initial `getChildData` call should fire something like `CHILD_DATA_REQUEST` action, which is the one the saga should be watching for.

```
// Description: Async Request to Get Child Data for Vendors/Sets
export function getChildData(
  id: string,
) {
  return { type: CHILD_DATA_REQUEST, id };
}

// In your saga watcher function
const childWatcher = yield takeLatest(CHILD_DATA_REQUEST, getChildDataAsync);
```

Once triggered, `getChildDataAsync` will be called and `CHILD_DATA_SUCCESS` will be triggered on request success, which I guess is the intended behaviour (and makes sense considering common actions naming).